# Why is electric flux zero if my point charge is outside of a sphere?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, electric-fields, gauss-law

I am currently studying Gauss Law and Electric flux , during one of my exercises they ask me to find the electric flux of a sphere with radius  5 cm and my  point charge is 10 cm to the left of the center of this sphere. Why is it that the electric flux is 0 if the  Electric field is not 0?

Comment: I just started and barely understand what the OP is talking about. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Gauss's law states that the flux of  the **net electric field** is equal to the charge enclosed inside it over $\epsilon_o$.

The flux due to all charges that lie outside of the closed surface is zero. (i.e. because they are not enclosed by the surface)

In a simplified explanation, all field lines that enter the closed surface from outside must also leave the region enclosed by the closed surface at another point.

The flux due to the field lines entering is cancelled out by that of the field lines leaving. (because they have opposite signs.)

This is why the flux due to external charges is zero.